# How can I pass a reference of the object to which .tagsinput() is applying to the typeahead source function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, bootstrap-tags-input

I am experimenting with bootstrap-tagsinput and typeahead.js to provide tags-based input mechanism for a user to select one or more of a collection of available tags. These tags match possible values in a server-side flags enum which the server-side model binder likes to see in a comma-separated list (making a set of tags perfect).

The dialog in which this will appear will have a large number of such inputs -- each with varying available tags (usually four or five each). What I'd like to be able to do is populate each input with an attribute that contains a comma-separated list of of possible tag values which typeahead can read from.

This is an example of a chunk of javascript that works for a single input:

```
$('#ExampleInput').tagsinput({
    allowDuplicates: false,
    freeInput: false,
    typeaheadjs: [
        {
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 0
        }, {
            source: function (query, syncResults) {
                // an array that will be populated with substring matches
                var matches = [];

                // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
                var substrRegex = new RegExp(query, 'i');

                // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
                // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
                $.each($('#ExampleInput').attr('data-values').split(','), function(i, str) {
                    if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                        matches.push(str);
                    }
                });

                syncResults(matches);
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

And this is an example of what the input looks like: (with some unrelated data validation and such removed for clarity)

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-values="Tag1,Tag2,Tag3,Tag4" id="ExampleInput" name="ExampleInput" type="text" value="Tag1, Tag2, Tag3, Tag4" />
```

As you can see, the source function that feeds the typeahead bits reference the #ExampleInput's data-values attribute to pull the list of available tags. This all works exactly as I'd like it to.

The problem I have is that I'd like to be able to apply this approach on a large scale targeting a class of inputs rather than individually for each input. I can't see how to make the source function aware of the target input object (#ExampleInput) so that it can track down the correct attribute specific to the input it's providing a source for.

Is this possible? Or would I have to pair each input with its own static typeahead source?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a pretty dumb sort of thing. I was hung up on using $(this) as I might usually within a jQuery statement like this. That wouldn't work as $(this) was the document within the scope of the typeaheadjs configuration statement.

I just ended up using a jQuery $.each() after the class selector and then using the assigned variable from the foreach within the typeahead source call.

For example:

```
var simpleSource = function (strings) {
    return function (query, syncResults) {
        var matches = [];

        var substrRegex = new RegExp(query, 'i');

        $.each(strings, function(i, str) {
            if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                matches.push(str);
            }
        });

        syncResults(matches);
    }
}

$('.target-class').each(function (index, target) {
    $(target).tagsinput({
        allowDuplicates: false,
        freeInput: false,
        typeaheadjs: [
            {
                hint: true,
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 0
            }, {
                source: simpleSource($(target).attr('data-values').split(","))
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

*(this version just abstracts the source function into a reusable function -- semantically similar to the version in the question)*

So, that ended up being a jQuery/JavaScript 101 thing, not a deficiency around typeahead or tagsinput. Nothing to see here... move along. :-)